# Apache Redirect based on directory match & Add another letter to the destination URL

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2, regex

So here’s what I’m trying to accomplish. I have this link, I want to 301 redirect:

Origin URL:

`https://www.example.com/folder1/page.aspx?fh_location=%2f%2fpackages%2fnl_BE%2fpr_earlybookable%3E%7b0%7d%2fpk_active%3d1%2fpk_siteswitch%3E%7bnvb%7d%2fpk_country%3E%7biso_pt%7d%2fpk_city%3E%7bgeo_9833%7d%2fpr_duration%3E%7b0608%7d%2fpk_hotelonly%3d0&fh_sort_by=pr_defaultprice&fh_secondid=nbs_city_cli16a_s18&fh_view=detail&fh_eds=%C3%9F&RoomOccupation1=CLI16A_2a_LO_2_0`

**Condition 1:** I have a list of Directories such as `folder1`, `folder2`, `folder3`, `folder4`. I want to redirect only if the URL contains any of the folders listed above, but not for `folder5` or any other folders not listed above in the URL.

**Condition 2:** Now comes the tricky part; in the destination it should take the id `cli16a` from the URL `fh_secondid=nbs_city_cli16a_s18` and then append to the destination URL as seen below

- `https://www.example.com/be/_CLI16AY/`

**Condition 3:** Now the most tricky part. Add that `Y` to the destination URL, which represents the folder in the origin URL, eg., `folder1` = `Y`, `folder2` = `O`, `folder3` = `B`, `folder4` = `C`.

So far I have come up with the below.

```
RewriteMap WE NEED TO GET A MAPPING OF TYPE OF HOTEL (not sure what to put here)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ==(folder1|folder2|folder3|folder4) [NC]
RewriteCond ${conv-lc:%{QUERY_STRING}} (fh_secondid)=[^_]+_[^_]+_([^_]+)_
RewriteRule ^/nl/_USE RewriteMap Matching text here/ ( not sure what to put here)
```

Comment: In the param value "nbs_city_cli16a_s18", is the "nbs_city" part constant, or is the required ID always the 3rd part (separated by underscores), which seems to be the method used in your code sample? Is this always lowercase? Should the ID in the resulting URL always be uppercase? I notice in your original URL that the ID seems to appear twice, the second occurance is already uppercase - or is this unreliable?

Comment: 1. The required ID always the 3rd part
2. This is not case sensitive for the resulting URL to work
3. As the resulting url can either be lowercase or uppercase, we can take the first occurrence which is the 3rd part  (separated by underscores)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the sounds of it, you don't necessarily *need* a `RewriteMap`, providing the number of directories is limited, which they appear to be, and the ID is not case-sensitive in the target URL, which you say is not (in comments).

For the ID *suffix* ("Y", "O", "B" or "C") we can create an environment variable, based on the directory being requested:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Assign value to ID_SUFFIX based on the directory being accessed
RewriteRule ^/?folder1 - [E=ID_SUFFIX:Y]
RewriteRule ^/?folder2 - [E=ID_SUFFIX:O]
RewriteRule ^/?folder3 - [E=ID_SUFFIX:B]
RewriteRule ^/?folder4 - [E=ID_SUFFIX:C]
```

Then, only process the request further if the `ID_SUFFIX` env var has been set, capturing the required ID from the query string:

```
# Capture ID and redirect
RewriteCond %{ENV:ID_SUFFIX} .
REwriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} fh_secondid=[^_]+_[^_]+_([^_]+)
RewriteRule ^ /be/_%1%{ENV:ID_SUFFIX}/ [R=302,L]
```

The expression `%{ENV:ID_SUFFIX}` naturally refers to the env var set earlier (if at all). Initially, we simply check that this is set (ie. contains *something*) - it is only set if one of the named directories has been requested.

`%1` is a backreference to the first captured group in the last matched *CondPattern*. ie. This holds the ID (eg. `cli16a` in your example).

This then constructs a *substitution* of the form `/be/_cli16aY/` and issues an external redirect.

Note that this is currently a 302 (temporary) redirect. Only change it to a 301 (permanent) when you are sure it's working OK, in order to avoid potenatial caching issues.